# Reuse the value of a type parameter in java

Tags: java, generics, annotations

I just saw someone post the following, in a rant on ugly code:

```
public static 
    Tuple<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>, 
          ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>>     
    split(
          ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> data, [..]);
```

(layout by me, in a laughable attempt to get this semi-readable)

I've been looking for a way to make this look a bit like this (non-functional) code:

```
TypeParam T = ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>;
public static Tuple<T,T> split( T data, [..]);
```

So far the best solution I've found is to define a class (in this ex. a class `Data`), which extends `ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>`, which would make the code look like this:

```
public static Tuple<Data, Data> split( Data data, [..]);
```

While this method is quite satisfactory, I don't want to give up on the possibility that there is some way of using generics that I'm missing, and I'm wondering if Java has a way of doing this in an even more aesthetically pleasing way.

Another solution I'm playing with is using an Annotation Processor to fix this for me, however I feel this misses a certain amount of simplicity.

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to code too lispy in java? I can't think of a case of a list-of-lists-of-lists-of-strings that doesn't deserve its own class in any OO language if there is a need for such list. (sorry, don't know about the generics)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. It is more of a hypothetical situation which had me wondering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
 public static <T extends ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> Tuple<T,T> 
      split(T data);
```

But I agree with @esej that you probably want some class to encapsulate the list-of-lists-of-lists-of-strings data structure.

I am also not sure if you should have `ArrayList` hard-coded in there (as opposed to using the interface `List`).

Comment: Oh, wow.. how did I miss that?!

I agree with the rarity of the situation, it's more of a hypothetical question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
public static <T extends List<List<List<String>>>>  Tuple<T, T> split(T data) {

}
```

Doesn't make it look any better IMO.